# How to process gtag events in Google Analytics interface?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, click-tracking

I am developing a landing page for a chrome extension. So I'd like to set some goals to track clicks to installation button, installation events, etc.

According to the [docs](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/events), I created few events

```js
// Click to the top install btn
gtag('event', 'install', {
    'event_label': 'click_top'
});

// Successful instalation
gtag('event', 'install', {
    'event_label': 'install_success'
});
```

(I can see via network panel that these action runs correct)

In the next step, I configured the goals catching in GA interface

- action: install
- label: click_top

[image]

**Problem:** 
But even after that I still have conversion rate 0% (I test it on myself). 
My questions are:

1. Did I set it wrong?
2. Is that possible that GA does not process my own clicks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that gtag is the tracker object based on event tracking in Google Analytics, I can see that "install" should is the category and not action.

In the screenshot where you are defining the goal, you are checking against action. Just change that and it should work. Another way of checking this is in your Google Analytics account, go to Behavior > Top Events and see if you have events falling under the "install" category.

Comment: I've checked configuration and it looks still to be correct. I know that params look confusing, but they just not in order with UI.
The problem solved by itself: the goals just don't count in the first 24hrs. I don't know why. Then it started to work correctly. 
But thank you for the advice.